# can it be a period instead of comma?

Tags: punctuation

**Can the first comma be replaced with a period? 
I think this is a non-essential relative clause, but I feel it can be two separate sentences.**

> Scientists have found a promising alternative to fear aversion therapy that involves using brain scanning technology and artificial intelligence to create “decoded neurofeedbac**k”, a** method that essentially erases the fearful memories from one’s mind without needing to evoke **them,** making it less traumatizing for people who don’t wish to relive their fears through aversion therapy.

**Even for the second comma, so it becomes:**

> Scientists have found a promising alternative to fear aversion therapy that involves using brain scanning technology and artificial intelligence to create “decoded neurofeedback”**. A** method that essentially erases the fearful memories from one’s mind without needing to evoke **them.** Making it less traumatizing for people who don’t wish to relive their fears through aversion therapy.

Answer (score 4):

No; when you break the sentence this way:

- The second 'sentence' in your rewrite is only a noun phrase (*a method*) with a modifying relative clause (*that . . . them*). There's no finite verb and no indication of whether it's a subject or a complement.
- The third 'sentence' is a verb phrase headed by a non-finite verb (*making*). There's no subject and no finite verb.

To form complete sentences you must supply the missing components:

> Scientists have found a promising alternative to fear aversion therapy that involves using brain scanning technology and artificial intelligence to create “decoded neurofeedback”. ***This is*** a method that essentially erases the fearful memories from one’s mind without needing to evoke them. ***That makes*** <s>Making</s> it less traumatizing for people who don’t wish to relive their fears through aversion therapy.

Comment: I agree in general, but find the use of **that** in the third sentence to be problematic. Personally, I would say ***This*** *erasure makes it . . .* (Making it **this** and also clarifying the referent.)

Comment: @JasonBassford Well, sorta. a) I was trying to keep the editing minimal and directed to the syntactic point at hand. b) Two *this*es with different referents is itself problematic. c) My *that* doesn't have just the erasure as its referent, but the entire erasure-without-evocation.

Comment: I can see the desire to not use *this* twice, but I'm not sure if *that* should be used at all. How about starting the third sentence with *it*?

Comment: @JasonBassford Or you could just use the original single sentence, which is clunky but clear.

Comment: Good point. Just because you *can* rewrite it, that doesn't mean you *should*. ;)